# how to find the .class file after running a .java project on vscode for macOS?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to find the .class file after running a java project in VScode on macOS, I searched Google but there is only a path for Windows OS. Can anyone help to figure out the .class file?
This is the java project's name: testSearch.java

[image]

I want to find the testSearch.class file after running.

Answer (score 1):

##### Explanation

By default, VSCode outputs '.class' files into different locations depending on the type of file you're working with:-

1. If you run a single '.java' file, it'll output the '.class' file into a path that looks like this: /private/var/folders/ys/rgjr_wyd0d715dz546hydfrr0000gn/T/vscodesws_6d2aa/jdt_ws/jdt.ls-java-project/bin
   [image]
2. If you open a folder that contains '.java' files and run them, the '.class' files will be inside of a path that looks like this: /Users/YourUserNameHere/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/e358195aec7543686cb2440051c91f82/redhat.java/jdt_ws/SplayTree Project_d551e7d6/bin
   [image]

---

##### Solutions

1. To find the output path for your **own** project, just look for it inside VSCode's terminal after running.
2. To change the default output directory for compiled '.class' files:
   Go to VSCode settings -> Search for "java project output path" -> Click on "Edit in settings.json" -> Add the desired path inside the quotation marks (Note: this will only work with Workspace projects. It won't work with Maven/Gradle).

[image]
[image]